# Port forwarding i try everything

Tags: port-forwarding

i want make counter strike 1.6 server but i have private ip so i try port forwarding port 27015
i try everything so if you can give me some advice

some picture

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGeGF.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Und5H.png)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtBbW.png)
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmShU.png)
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfVbq.png)
[6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cjqss.png)
[7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKu5r.png)

Comment: You could try ngrok, which is mentioned in [Set up a web server behind a Carrier Grade NAT](https://superuser.com/questions/1258093/set-up-a-web-server-behind-a-carrier-grade-nat)

Answer (score 1):

On your WAN side you have a 10.x.x.x IP - so your NAT is behind a NAT on your carrier's side (cgNAT). This means, that you can not accept connections (i.e. run a server) without your ISP configuring it in their NAT.

Most likely you have some residential-grade internet access, where running a server is explicitly ruled out in the TOS, so this will be hard to near impossible to achieve.

Comment: so i must contact my ISP ?

Comment: First you must check your TOS - most likely these will say, that you can't run a server.

Comment: @MarekUhrik You will need to contact your ISP and request a public routable IP address, either DHCP or statically assigned... There is typically a higher monthly charge for this, and sometimes a "setup" fee as well, the charges can be significant in some regions or require you to get a commercial/business account (which also can be significantly more expensive). Note that some ISPs do not have this service available for residential customers at all, and in some cases it is as simple as placing your existing "modem" in bridge mode or getting a different one from your ISP.