# How to connect to a PC in LAN from the Internet (No static IP)

Tags: networking

The PC (Raspberry) is in a LAN Network and I want to connect to it, however the network doesn't have a static IP.
Additionally I can't use Port forwarding and Dynamic DNS.

What other options do I have?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot connect to the Raspberry, your only option is for it to connect
to you.

You need to set up a VPN server, reachable via the Internet, and have the
Raspberry connect to that server.

Your computer can then also join that VPN network, for the Raspberry to become
accessible.

Beware that in a corporate environment this may cause some alarm,
so better get first the required authorization.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily.

Its worth remembering that packets from the outside wouldn't know how to reach you and working between two dynamic endpoints is... challenging. Assuming you're using a raspberry pi cause its cheap - spending extra money isn't really an option.

[Essentially this problem seems identical to trying to connect to a system inside a carrier grade nat.](https://superuser.com/a/1258102/10165)

The solution is basically "If you cannot connect in, connect out" and establish the connection from your system. Which is tricky if your endpoint dosen't have a staticish, routable IP

There's a bunch of possible solutions - find a service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) if its just a web server that handles the connections for you.

Some time back I'd have suggested ipv6 - I used to use a defunct tunnel broker provider that worked behind a nat - if you can find a provider that works for you 
(or its supported by your endpoints), its probably the 'neatest' way to get this working.

You might also be able to use a third party VPN that works behind a nat. Back in the old days, we used to run lan games over the internet  using hamachi - though [zerotier](https://www.zerotier.com) seems to be a more modern alternative. They do have a fairly reasonable free tier.

Basically - any options you have will be limited, involve a fair amount of extra work or cost.