# Is it possible for an ISP to identify and block attempts to run a webserver?

Tags: remote-desktop, internet, webserver

Very long story short, I phoned my ISP to unlock port forwarding and they did so without charging me. I can access literally anything running at any port in my computer, either through a free DDNS address I got or directly using my IP. Except for webservers.

There's ports 80/443 and other random ports I chose are forwarded and unlocked in the firewall. I can run Plex, Calibre, Bittorrent and other webUI's just fine. I also can ping myself via DNS or IP. However, the moment I run a webserver, the ports I set them to use timeout when accessed from the internet. It doesn't matter if it's Apache, Lighttpd, easyPHP, Mongoose, Fenix Webserver, if it's Windows or Linux, it just doesn't work and I find no other explanation other than my ISP is somehow blocking it :/

PS: I always tested from another network, using more than one device/browser. From within my network, connection works just fine.

PPS: Here are my port forwarding settings.

[image]

Comment: How did you go about port forwarding your router? You would need to set the ports you want open for both TCP/UDP and set the ip address of the machine in the router configuration itself. Also, do you happen to know what the model of your router is?

Comment: That's how I did it => https://imgur.com/tnMPDm5
I don't see any problems with. Someone just told me it could be the ports 80/443 are locked by the ISP. I just make sure once again and set my torrent webUI to listen to each of them. Then I connected to another internet connection using my smartphone and I could access it from said ports normally. It's very strange.

Comment: One more thing to rule out would be something called Carrier-Grade NAT which would prevent a webserver from communicating out. You can check if you are on such a network by checking your public ip address on a site like whatismyip.com and seeing if it is different than one assigned to your gateway. You'll be able to compare it to what is listed in your router's WAN public/IP section.

Comment: @iskyfire if you're talking about a double NAT, yes I have a double NAT situation, that's something I know for some time already. 
In other words, my public IP is not the same as the WAN IP listed in my router, it has never been.

Comment: This must be the issue. There is another question that has more information on CGNAT: https://superuser.com/questions/1258093/set-up-a-web-server-behind-a-carrier-grade-nat I recommend the solution provided by @davidgo to setup a VPN.

Comment: @iskyfire just to get some context. It appears (as implied in the first answer in the thread you mentioned) that all of the problems with a CGNAT would be to get your ports forwarded. My ports are forwarded and I can access any of them, up to port 65535.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible for an ISP to do it, although it would be uncommon. They can do things as simple as block port 80 and 443 (easy to implement, easy to work arround) to traffic sniffing (hard to implementement, hard to work arround)

I could not see your Imgur image from my device, so I may be talking about something you have ruled out, but its quite common that routers run their own web servers and don't forward traffic on ports 80 and 443.  The work-arround - if its not for looks - is to put your web servers external IP on other ports.

If this fails, you can say stuff it, get a VPN with a static IP and bypass your router and ISP totally.

Comment: Yes, getting a VPN is an option but in actuality I won't need that since I won't be hosting a web server. I just needed it to validate an SSL certificate, which I've done by other means. 

On the other hand, as I said before, I can't run webservers on ANY port, but I can do so with other services. In other words, it's neither the router using ports 80/443 now would it be of any use to set the web server to use other ports, since it remains inaccessible anyways.

Comment: @ezequielbarbosa How bizarre. I imagine the next step is to break out a traffic sniffer like tcpdump and see what, if any communications are taking place at various points (assuming you can run tcpdump on your router - I know dd-wrt flashed routers can)

Comment: I called my ISP and they told me they block those ports for home users and that's why I can't access a Web server. They say I can only use ports in the range 1024-65535. That was the answer by I tried again and I can indeed use any port I want from 80-65535 though, just not with webserver. They assured me that if I pay the premium everything will work right, so, anyways.