# How to port forward on a private ip

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I wanted to port forward so I can host my own MC server etc... But I realized that my router's public ip is private. Any suggestions I'm using TL-WR740N
Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set up a web server behind a Carrier Grade NAT](https://superuser.com/questions/1258093/set-up-a-web-server-behind-a-carrier-grade-nat)

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/1619788/how-to-port-forward-on-a-private-ip

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible without the support of your upstream provider - who would need to set up port forwards on their equipment to your router.

An alternative us to bypass the problem using a VPN with a static IP provider or doing a reverse tunnel through another box with a known IP (eg using SSH)

Answer (score -1):

This is typically done in the case of a server on your network that has a private IP, when you would like to make the server publicly accessible through it’s public IP address. You would set this up in a firewall by configuring the NAT settings.

Comment: This is not a correct answer. The question explicitly states that the router’s public (which I assume to mean WAN side) IP address is a private address, i.e. their provider probably uses carrier grade NAT.

Comment: I don't know only thing I know that is my WAN ip is private (router) and the device that gives me internet and others is in my roof.