# Can't Access Local Server from Public IP

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

I want to port forward port 3002 and allow others to connect to it over the internet. I set up a node server and when entering `http://localhost:3002/` on my local computer I get a *"Hello world!"* message.

The computer on my network hosting the server is @ `192.168.0.182` running Linux. I configured the "virtual servers" feature on my TP-Link A6 Archer router with the internal and external port set to 3002 and set the IP to my computer's local IP.
[image: router screenshot]

After saving the changes and going to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/, I get told that the port is still closed. Although the router settings say blocking ping packets is disabled, I can't ping my own IP either.

`http://192.168.0.182:3002` on my local network does get me a reply from the server I'm hosting.

I heard the ISP might be doing this, but how would this even work?

Router info page:
[image: dd]

Comment: Before checking from the outside, a first test to do would be from another device on the same network. Can you access `http://192.168.0.182:3002/` from another device on the same local network?

Comment: “how would this even work?” - If you are behind a CGNAT you essentially don’t have the ability to port forward.

Comment: Two other things you can add to your question: Does this TP-Link router have a public IP for the WAN IP, or it's behind another router? Can you share a screenshot of the Virtual Servers page on the router with the rule?

Comment: I edited added in that I can access the server locally. the WAN IP i'm assuming is this: https://snipboard.io/oqtKEC.jpg

Comment: `10.0.203.167` is not a public IP, which is why it cannot be accessed from the internet.

Comment: When you tried https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ did you enter `10.0.203.167` in the Remote Address box or used the IP (a different one, a public IP) that was there?

Comment: I used the public IP since it's the one sites like myip.com give me. What's the difference between them?

Comment: @BlackShibe - 10.0.203.167 isn’t a public ip address and thus cannot be accessed by anyone. Your behind a CGNAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your router (the TP-Link Archer A6) does not have a public IP address, therefore it cannot be directly accessed from the internet, and the Virtual Servers/Port Forwarding rule on it doesn't help to getting up to this router from the public Internet.

The IP address the router has is `10.0.203.167` which is a [Private IP Address](https://www.arin.net/reference/research/statistics/address_filters/) and cannot be reached from the internet.

In order from anything to be able (and know where to go) to start a connection to your local device, it needs an open path from the Internet to your local device. In your situation, while you gave it a path (by setting it up in the router's Virtual Servers) from the `10.0.203.167` router to the `192.168.0.182` server, there is still no way for anything to start a connection from your public IP (which is the one *sites like myip.com give* you, and the only IP that can be accessed on the internet) to `10.0.203.167`.

If the TP-Link router is connected to another router (or modem-router combo) which you have access to log in to, you can check on that one if that one does show the public IP address as its WAN address, and if so you can do port forwarding on that one (or some other setting like Bridge Mode, or DMZ.) If you do not have such a device then it would mean that you're behind your ISP's CGNAT and cannot really have a direct connection to your server (see this answer for some more details/ideas https://superuser.com/a/1258102/368970)